# How to revert updates? Apple OSX El Capitan update 10.11.6 destroyed OSX Server

Tags: macos, osx-server

I have paid and installed OSX Server on OSX and everything was running fine.
The OSX told me there are some beautiful and important updates ready for me to be install and I trusted OSX and to my regret I pressed the Update button.

Now the Mac did magic work and restarted and the OSX server is GONE :(

All my websites are DOWN :( Game Over..

---

Now AppStore in OSX asks me to pay and buy new OSX server. And even if I press Buy button then AppStore says: **We could not complete your purchase** Because OS X version 10.12.4 is required.

And I have OS X 10.11.6. All I want is to use this Mac as local server for developing. Now as the OSX Server wont start and it wont install I am stuck.

I opened Terminal window and wrote:

```
$ sudo apachectl restart
```

And I got apache working on port 80 (http) and the DocumentRoot folder is changed. Probably all settings changed.

Before I updated I had OSX Server working for SSL on port 443 + port 80.

---

The question:
How can I get OSX Server working?
Should I reinstall the OSX I have and never do the updates? Or can I revert this last update?

Comment: Did you restart the server app? I mean via Finder. apachctl is the wrongapproach.

Comment: @not2savvy When I start Server it gives ERROR: This version of Server is no longer supported on this version of OS X. Visit the Mac AppStore... And in AppStore I cant buy new one. It says OS X 10.2.4 is required.

Comment: You don't need to buy a new version, but you need to update your existing app. If an update is not offered, make sure you are logged on to the App Store using the same login which you had used when you originally bought the server app.